# ggplot arrows with dashed lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following trajectory:

```
test = data.frame(x = c(9500, 25500, 47500), y = c(10.03, 7.81, 0.27))
```

I want to plot this as a path with `ggplot2`, with an arrow identifying the direction:

```
ggplot(test) + aes(x = x, y = y) +
  geom_path(size = 1, 
    arrow = arrow(type = "open", angle = 30, length = unit(0.1, "inches")))
```

This looks fine. However, if I want to use a dashed line, the arrow is also drawn with a dashed line, which looks terrible:

```
ggplot(test) + aes(x = x, y = y) +
  geom_path(linetype ="dashed", size = 1, 
    arrow = arrow(type = "open", angle = 30, length = unit(0.1, "inches")))
```

Is there a way to exclude the `linetype` aesthetic from the arrow definition itself?

Comment: I think the only "solution" may be to use closed arrow heads. Would be a nice subject for an issue/PR (if I'm right that there isn't a "real" way...).

Comment: ...huh, it appears that this may be baked right into **grid** itself. It looks like, e.g. `segmentsGrob` draws both the line and the arrows, and takes only one set of `gpar` arguments. Not sure how you'd fix this without fixing it in **grid**.

Answer (score 7):

We can work around the issue by drawing the arrow head with a separate geometry that has a solid line.  Something like this:

```
geom_end_arrow = function(path, arrow, ...) {
  path = tail(path,2)
  x.len = diff(path$x)/1000
  y.len = diff(path$y)/1000
  path$x[1] = path$x[2] - x.len
  path$y[1] = path$y[2] - y.len
  geom_path(data = path, mapping = aes(x=x, y=y), arrow=arrow, ...)
}

ggplot(test) + aes(x = x, y = y) +
  geom_path(linetype ="dashed", size = 1) +
  geom_end_arrow(test, size = 1, arrow = arrow(type = "open", angle = 30, length = unit(0.1, "inches")))
```

[image]

Comment: This works for the simple example, but it's not useful for the general case (e.g. inheriting aesthetics or using a `group` aesthetic for multiple trajectories).